# GORM: How to link one to one?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to load queue items from my database. I've created an API endpoint but I can't get the data for the queue item to preload. Instead the entire "data" object is full of empty values.

Handler:

```
func QueueItemHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var queueItems QueueItem
    var builder = database.Model(QueueItem{})

    var queryError = builder.
        Preload("Status").
        Preload("Data").
        Find(&queueItems).
        Error

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(queueItems)
}
```

Here is how my gorm models are set up:

```
type QueueItemStatus struct {
    ID          int64  `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
}

type QueueItemData struct {
    ID            int64  `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    QueueItemId   int64  `json:"queue_item_id"`
    ScreenshotUrl string `json:"screenshot_url"`
}

type QueueItem struct {
    ID            int64                  `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    SourceUrl     string                 `json:"source_url"`
    OriginId      int64                  `json:"origin_id"`
    StatusId      int64                  `json:"status_id"`
    Status        QueueItemStatus `json:"status"`
    Data          QueueItemData   `json:"data" gorm:"foreignKey:id,references:queue_item_id"`
    CreatedAt     time.Time              `json:"created_at"`
}
```

I'm thinking maybe I have the models set up pointing to the wrong columns if anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this

```
Data       QueueItemData    `json:"data" gorm:"foreignKey:QueueItemId;references:ID"`
```